# Table row Values changes based on selected drop down jquery ajax php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to create a page which has a form which contains Total and Converted Total Value. And this total is generating from a do while loop in php. At top there is a currency drop down. When i select any currency from the dropdown, the page redirects in ajax mode to another php page called currency1.php and get the required values from currency1.php and fill the appropriate values in Converted total value. Following is the markup page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Get Currency Values</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#cur').change(function() {
                $.get('currency1.php', {
                    cur: $(this).val()
                }, function(data) {
                    $('#emp_id').val(data);
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <table border=1>
        <tr>
            <td colspan=3>
                <select name="cur" id="cur">
                    <option value="1">US Dollar</option>
                    <option value="2">Indian Rupee</option>
                    <option value="3">British Pound</option>
                    <option value="4">Euro</option>
                    <option value="5">Singapore Dollar</option>
                    <option value="6">Australian Dollar</option>
                    <option value="7">Canadian Dollar</option>
                    <option value="8">Swiss Franc</option>
                    <option value="9">Japanese Yen</option>
                    <option value="10">Malaysian Ringgit</option>
                    <option value="11">South African Rand</option>
                </select>
                <input type="text" name="emp_id" id="emp_id" />
            </td>
            {Do while loop in PHP}
            <tr>
                <td><b>Total Value</b>
                </td>
                <td><b>Converted Value</b>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="box1" id="box1" value="1000">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="con_ver1" id="con_ver1" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="box2" id="box2" value="2200">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="con_ver2" id="con_ver2" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="box3" id="box3" value="900">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="con_ver3" id="con_ver3" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="box4" id="box4" value="3200">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="con_ver4" id="con_ver4" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan=2>The Records continues..........</td>
            </tr>
            {end of php do while loop}
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

My currency1.php which is getting the ajax query is as follows: This page should return back the results in array to the previous page. Iam not getting how to achieve this in array and return back the results in ajax. Currency1.php is as follows:

```
 <?php
 include('config.php');

$sql = "select rate from currency1 where currency='INR' LIMIT 1";

$result_gt = mysql_query($sql) or die($sql."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
$list_gt = mysql_fetch_array($result_gt);
$inrvalue=$list_gt['rate'];


 if(isset($_REQUEST['cur'])){
  // connection should be on this page  
     $sql = mysql_query("select currency,rate from currency1 where id =".$_REQUEST['cur']);
     $res = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
     $rate=$res['rate'];

  //$gt=($inrvalue*10)/$res['rate'];

  //$gt=($inrvalue*10)/$res['rate'];
  //$gt=($inrvalue/$rate)*total[$i];
  $gt=($inrvalue/$rate);

   echo json_encode($gt);die;
  }
  ?>
```

Is my coding correct? Is there any other procedure to achieve the same. I mean with just javascript? Pls help me? Thanx in advance.

Comment: Are you going to make a new PHP file for each currency? You should do a generic php, which get the required currency by parsing $_POST, call that in sql and then generate the table.

Comment: No iam not going to make a php file for each currency. yes i understood the method i need to follow. Yes i know till to generate the table. But what after that. How will i pass the values to the first page back. From the markup which i have pasted you will be having a fair idea on the fields. Now i need to pass the values to the markuppage or the firstpage. 

Your help will be appreciated. Thanx in advance

Answer (score 0):

#### Basic concept

You should rewrite your success function, instead of:

```
function(data) {
    $('#emp_id').val(data);
});
```

Put some code that parse the json and produce a table content, **for example**:

```
function(data) {
    var content_table = '';
    var array_data = JSON.parse(data);
    for(var i=0; i<array_data.length; i++){
        var line_content = array_data[i];
        //TODO: set up correctly the line content...
        var line_html = '<td>'+line_content+'</td>';
        //...once done, append to the html
        content_table+='<tr>'+line_content+'</tr>';
    }
    //update table body (do not reload the full page)
    $('tbody').html(content_table);
});
```

#### Better way, using the library

According to [the library documentation](https://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html), you can load directly the json by :

```
$(selector_datatable).dataTable( {
    "ajax": '../ajax/data/arrays.txt'
} );
```

I your case, that file is generated by the php script.

The flaw is that every web browser will see the same result, because you load a hard set file.

To get a personalized experience to all users, you can either produce a file for each currency, or [go to real ajax](https://www.datatables.net/examples/server_side/simple.html).

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you. i will try this. Iam very new to Ajax and need do some trial and errors...